# Serve php RESTful server with apache2 (ubuntu)

Tags: php, apache, unix, ubuntu, virtualhost

I have a ubuntu machine on which I want to run a php rest server. Here is my default config file:

```
ServerName localhost
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/otherSite
   ServerName www.vlio20_paka.com
   Alias /otherSite /var/www/html/otherSite
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/lbserver/public
  ServerName www.vlio20_lb.com
  Alias /lbServer /var/www/lbserver/public
  <Directory /var/www/lbserver/public>
     AllowOverride all
     DirectoryIndex index.php
     Require all granted
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

In my public directory I have .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

When I try to access the server `http://MACHINE_IP/lbServer`
I am getting *Not Found* error.

How can I make it work 
(I am doing apache restart after each change in the config file)?

**Update:**

`apache2 -t` produced:

```
[Sun Jun 28 12:00:00.789522 2015] [core:warn] [pid 22089] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} is not defined
[Sun Jun 28 12:00:00.789835 2015] [core:warn] [pid 22089] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_PID_FILE} is not defined
[Sun Jun 28 12:00:00.789970 2015] [core:warn] [pid 22089] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_USER} is not defined
[Sun Jun 28 12:00:00.790088 2015] [core:warn] [pid 22089] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP} is not defined
[Sun Jun 28 12:00:00.790240 2015] [core:warn] [pid 22089] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Sun Jun 28 12:00:00.794721 2015] [core:warn] [pid 22089:tid 140102153521024] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Sun Jun 28 12:00:00.795136 2015] [core:warn] [pid 22089:tid 140102153521024] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Sun Jun 28 12:00:00.795200 2015] [core:warn] [pid 22089:tid 140102153521024] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
AH00526: Syntax error on line 74 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid Mutex directory in argument file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}
```

**note:** the first site is loading fine but the second gives a 404 error.

Comment: The command to restart your apache server is `sudo service apache2 restart`.  Just reloading your config (`reload` instead of `restart`) might also work and is slightly faster.

Comment: I did both, sudo service apache2 reload & sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: This means that unless those commands procuded error messages, your configs are valid.  Note that there is not `httpd` binary on Ubuntu systems, it's called `apache2` and should in general not be called directly.

Comment: restart = stop + start, reload = remain running + re-read configuration files.

Comment: @vlio20 the default `httpd.conf` on linux systems is `apache.conf`. Have you checked the line 74 ?

Comment: Yes, I the configuration is changing. but I can't make more then 1 virtual host on the same port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First this as almost nothing to do with a REST problem. It is a simple configuration error.

Second, for `apache2 -t` you should run `. /etc/apache2/envvars` before, because you need some envs variables loaded.

Then the configuration problem.

Your are defining 2 named based Virtualhosts, 1 with the name `www.vlio20_paka.com` and one with the name `www.vlio20_lb.com`. The first one is defined first, so if you use an unknown name it will be used, by default.

When you make a query this way:

```
http://MACHINE_IP/lbServer
```

the Host header used in your HTTP query is `MACHINE_IP`, so it's not `www.vlio20_paka.com` and not `www.vlio20_lb.com`. If you have no other default virtualhost (something you would find using `apache2 -S`) the first one will be used.

Let's have a look at the first one:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/otherSite
   ServerName www.vlio20_paka.com
   Alias /otherSite /var/www/html/otherSite
</VirtualHost>
```

If we fall here the path searched on your disk will be `DocumentRoot`+`url`, so `/var/www/html/otherSite/lbServer`. You have a **404**, chances are this path does not exists.

Note that your `Alias` instructions here simply tells Apache that a request to http://www.vlio20_paka.com/ and a request to http://www.vlio20_paka.com/otherSite would both point to the `/var/www/html/otherSite/` directory, maybe not what you wanted to do.

`Alias` is simply a way to define some sort of url symlinks on the url-to-filesystem maps.

Let's now look the second VirtualHost, that you can only reach if you use the right name in your HTTP request, that is not requesting http://MACHINE_IP/lbServer but http://www.vlio20_lb.com/lbServer (for that you could an entry in your /etc/hosts file, on the machine running the http query).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/lbserver/public
  ServerName www.vlio20_lb.com
  Alias /lbServer /var/www/lbserver/public
  <Directory /var/www/lbserver/public>
     AllowOverride all
     DirectoryIndex index.php
     Require all granted
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

So here you set a DocumentRoot at `/var/www/lbserver/public` but also, via `Alias`, you tell Apache that a request to http://www.vlio20_lb.com/lbServer/ point to the same entry as http://www.vlio20_lb.com/.

Your best fix would be to add an entry in `/etc/hosts` a request your test websites with real names, so that you can use Name based VirtualHosting. Or use only one VirtualHost and try things with aliases, but that's usually far from the production settings.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I think of without seeing more of your config.

Change:

```
<Directory /lbserver>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</Directory>
```

To:

```
<Directory /lbserver>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: It didn't help. any thing else I can do or details I ca add?

Comment: What happens when you go to `http://127.0.0.1/` (or the `MACHINE_IP`). Did you restart apache after the change? Also does `/path/to/httpd -t` say?

Comment: I have other sites on this machine so `http://127.0.0.1/` (MACHINE_IP) so my default site is seen ( a static one). See question for output of httpd -t

Comment: It seems there is no httpd.conf in my etc/apache2 directory

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu there is no binary httpd, apache2 used instead:

```
ricardo@zeus:~$ httpd -t
No se ha encontrado la orden «httpd», quizás quiso decir:
 La orden «xttpd» del paquete «xtide» (universe)
 La orden «https» del paquete «httpie» (universe)
 La orden «http» del paquete «httpie» (universe)
httpd: no se encontró la orden
ricardo@zeus:~$ apache2 -t
```

Now , paste the command output ;-)